# DefaultModelBinder Implementation does not populate the model - ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, defaultmodelbinder

I have a very simple implementation of the DefaultModelBinder, I need it to fire some custom validation.

```
public class MyViewModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder 
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ModelStateDictionary modelState = bindingContext.ModelState;
        var model = (MyViewModel)base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

        var result = ValidationFactory.ForObject<MyViewModel>().Validate(model);

        CustomValidation(result, modelState);

        return model;
    }
}
```

MyViewModel is a public sealed class.
The model binder is registered in the Global.asax this way:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyViewModel), new MyViewModelBinder());
```

The problem is that the model is never populated! But the MVC default model binder (I remove the registration in global.asax) works fine.

This is the view HTML:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="Name">Name</label></td>
            <td><input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="Code">Code</label></td>
            <td><input id="Code" name="Code" type="text" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table> </div>
```

Every field matches a property of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information you provided I am unable to reproduce the problem. Here's what I did.

View model:

```
public sealed class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        // at this stage the model is populated perfectly fine
        return View();
    }
}
```

Index View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="Name">Name</label></td>
                <td><input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="Code">Code</label></td>
                <td><input id="Code" name="Code" type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

Model binder:

```
public class MyViewModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var model = (MyViewModel)base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

        // at this stage the model is populated perfectly fine
        return model;
    }
}
```

So now the question is, how does your code differs than mine and what is it in those `CustomValidation` and `Validate` methods?

Comment: You are right. That's the right approach. It leaded me to the solution: the problem was in a property of MyViewModel throwing an exception. Thanks mate!